# Getting errors on mysql returned array

Tags: php, mysql

We are using following code for setters.

```
            if (is_numeric($id)) {

            global $db;

            $product = $db->query('SELECT id, name, code, amount FROM products WHERE id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1');

            print_r($product);
            echo $product['name'];

            if (!empty($product)) {

                $this->cId = $product['id'];

                $this->cName = $product['name'];

                $this->cDuration = $product['code'];

                $this->cCost = $product['amount'];

            }

            else return false;

        }

    }
```

But its giving following output with notices...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Gaming [code] => 12 [amount] => 20000 ) )
```

Notice: Undefined index: name in root//class.products.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined index: id in root/class.products.php on line 30

What are we doing wrong, please help, thanks.

Comment: Use `$product[0]['name']` instead of `$product['name']`. Your db-abstraction layer expects to return a whole resultset, not just a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$product` actually contains an array of an array, in which you want to access the first one by doing `$product[0]`

You want to do this instead:

```
$product[0]['id']

$product[0]['name']
```

and so on.

Comment: @seoppc It's not a *trick* if it's the necessary solution. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Your array has a nested array, so you'd need to access it using `$product[0]['name']`. There's still no key `'duration'` or `'fee'` in there though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a subarray. You can access it with `$product[0]['id']` for example
`